# can anyone send me some good links on cocoa touch framework?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone application development so that i want to learn cocoa touch framework.

As i want to read on cocoa touch framework if anyone can help me to find some good resources to learn the framework as

ebooks
tutorials and
videos

it will be very useful to me .

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971/can-anyone-recommend-a-complete-objc-cocoa-or-cocoa-touch-tutorial

Comment: thank you brad for showing me more answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Go through the links on this website: http://www.bestuniversities.com/blog/2009/100-free-courses-tutorials-for-aspiring-iphone-app-developers/.

2) Go through the reference guides and all the code samples on iPhone Dev Center's [Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html).

3) Go through Stanford's iPhone Course [CS193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php).

After doing the above steps (and lots of coding on your own), your skills will rock on \m/

Answer (score 1):

I started from Apple's [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/). It's quite nice source of recourses for iPhone/iPod Touch development.

Answer (score 1):

The search box is your friend :)  There is a great discussion here: [Howto Articles for iPhone Development Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Personally, I'd suggest starting with Aaron Hillegass' [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) and then read [Beginning iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592) by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche.

Apple has a lot of resources on their site: [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone)